# CSS image called in JavaScript function sometimes fails to load

Tags: javascript, css, file-upload, background-image

Sometimes, a CSS background image fails to load.  What might be the cause of this?

I have a Javascript code like this:

```
function progressBar(file_id) {

    pbar = ($("<div />").attr('id',file_id+"-statusicon").css({"background-image" : "url('../img/test-skip-icon.png')", "width" : "16px", "height" : "16px"}));
    $("#"+file_id+" .status").append(pbar);
}
```

and then I call it in another function:

```
progressBar(file_id);
```

The problem is that sometimes the image loads properly, and sometimes not. The png image size is about 9KB.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When it does not load, do you make sure the filename is correct?

Comment: where is this called from? is it wrapped within a $(document).ready()?

Comment: Relative background-URL links are relative to the CSS file, not to the HTML file or JS file. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: usually it does not load, on the very first time I try to upload file, it's like a little status icon to show the status of upload file. But if after the upload done, and I try to upload again, it will show up properly. Yes the path is correct. otherwise it would not show up all the time :)

Comment: @smerny whoops! I was looking for the tag and completely missed it in the code! :-[

Comment: Harts, any errors show in console?

Comment: Is your server a linux server? they are case sensitive. Check out for that too...

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal yes it is linux. but whether it's case sensitive or not, if it's show up before, then it should not be the case for the path.

Comment: you may want to pre-load the image before that call is made to ensure it is in the cache. There are many articles out there on pre-loading images. You may also want to consider using a data:uri for the image so it doesn't need to load from the file system at all.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to pre-load the image before that call is made to ensure it is in the cache. There are many articles out there on pre-loading images. You may also want to consider using a data:uri for the image so it doesn't need to load from the file system at all - Mike McCaughan